# Winning strategy in a pigeonhole principle related game

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, pigeonhole-principle, oracles

Let us have the following game. The player $F$ claims that the usual pigeonhole principle is not true and, moreover, they have a counterexample, i.e. a function which maps $n + 1$ pigeons injectively into $n$ holes for some finite $n$. The player $T$ does not agree with such a claim and wants to prove $F$ wrong. To achieve this, they ask $F$ questions of the following form: given a pigeon $a$, where should $a$ be mapped according to $F$. The player $T$ wins as soon as the $F$'s answer contradicts some information $T$ already has, i.e. $F$ claims that the pigeon $a$ should be mapped to the hole $b$, while $T$ already knows that $a$ is mapped to the hole $b' \neq b$. The problem is that $T$ has really small memory, in particular, they can store information about $2$ pigeons at the same time, and so before asking any new question, they must erase the oldest piece of information (and so immediately prior to asking such a question $T$ effectively has information about $1$ pigeon only).

It is not hard to show that that in this game $F$ can play in a way that $T$ will never catch them off guard and so $T$ can't possibly win. But there is one more rule. At some point $T$ can ask the last question, after which they will take the final piece of information and compare it with all the data they have gathered through the whole game (the data which has been erased). Note that they can compare the answers gathered through the whole game with the last answer only and not with each other. If they can find some contradiction with the $F$'s claim, they win.

Assume $T$ has some fixed strategy (i.e. each new question depends only on information which is in $T$'s memory and on the question's index) and assume the index of the final question is fixed as a part of the strategy. I would like to find an (elementary) proof that $F$ can still play in such a way that $T$ will not win in the end.

Comment: When you say "they can compare the answers gathered through the whole game with the last answer only", can you clarify what that means? EG If F said "pigeon A is in hole 1", can we compare against all questions about pigeon A AND all answers about hole 1? Or just the former/latter?

Comment: We can compare against both of these, e.g. for T to win it is enough that there has been an answer of the form A is somewhere besides 1 or there is some other pigeon besides A mapped to 1.

Comment: Does F know T's strategy ?

Comment: @WW1: Technically, it doesn't matter, since the question asks whether $F$ **can** still play in such way, which is independent of whether they know they're doing it or not. If the question was whether $F$ can know how to win, the assumption would have to be that $F$ knows $T$'s strategy, because otherwise it would be trivially impossible – $T$ could just fix a strategy of asking about each pigeon once and then asking the final question about some pigeon, and $F$ would have no way of making sure that that last pigeon wasn't assigned the same hole as another.

Comment: @WW1,  yes, $F$ knows a priori $T$'s strategy.

Comment: This isn't true for $n=1$ or $n=2$. $T$ can just ask about each pigeon in turn; you have to give different answers to successive questions; and then ending on the $n+1$-th question will reveal an inconsistency. Are you assuming $n\gt2$?

Comment: @joriki yes yes, sorry, we may assume $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

If F knows which pigeon (call it X) will be asked about in the final question, they can fool T into thinking that they can fit any number of pigeons into just 3 holes.

- If T asks about X, F answers hole #1
- Otherwise F answers either 2 or 3, depending on whether or not T is asking about the same pigeon they asked about in the previous question.